# I want to create a new Product, then add some Parts from another Document to that new ProductDoc, after two hours that seems impossible

Tags: vba, catia

It seems like I just cant add a copied Part two a productDoc. Its possible to paste it directly into the ProductDocument, but than I cant save it. What I need to do is:

1. Create ProductDoc
2. Create a ProductDoc in rootProductDoc
3. Copy Part from another Doc
4. Paste Part in ProductDoc from second step

Anyone an idea how to do that?

Im using CATIA V5-6 Release 2016, ServicePack 5 Build Number 26

There just dont seem any functions to select the ProductDoc from step 2.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks downvoters.

You cannot add a PartDocument itself to a Product, it needs to be a ProductDocument to which a Part is added (with AddNewComponent("Part","")).

```
Dim documents1 As Documents
Set documents1 = CATIA.Documents

Dim productDoc As ProductDocument
Set productDoc = documents1.Add("Product")

Dim rootProduct As Product
Set rootProduct = productDoc.Product

Dim childProduct As Product
Set childProduct = rootProduct.Products.AddNewComponent("Product", "")

Dim part1 As Product
Set part1 = childProduct.Products.AddNewComponent("Part", "")

Dim part2 As Product
Set part2 = childProduct.Products.AddNewComponent("Part", "")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing clean code. Very useful for new comers like me.

Answer (score 0):

MaxVR, thanks for coming back and posting the solution! It was really helpful for the product symmetry macro I'm working on. There's another way to insert parts into a CATProduct if the parts already exist.

```
'These three lines are variants
'products_variant_file_open represents the product that we want our part to be added to 
'variant_array_file_open is where we store our file path

Dim products_variant_file_open
Set products_variant_file_open = current_rh_product.Products
Dim variant_array_file_open(0)
variant_array_file_open(0) = root_file_location & "\" & current_product.PartNumber & "_RH.CATPart"

'Below is the command that inserts the CATPart. The left thing to specify is the array that holds 
'the file name and the right thing is the type of file to add
```

Here's some sample code that shows how I got my file path to insert parts from

```
'prod_doc.Path gets path of the product document and the stuff to the right becomes the folder name
root_file_location = prod_doc.Path & "\" & name_prod.Name & "_RH_Parts"
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
'Creates a folder in specified path with the specified name
fso.CreateFolder (root_file_location)
```

Then I used a function to loop through the folder and search for specific names

```
Function rh_folder_lookup(rh_part_file_name As String, 
root_file_location_func As String)



'Default rh folder lookup to be false when it's false we can't find a matching file in our folder so we make a new rh part
rh_folder_lookup = False
'Set the file name to all the files in our folder
Dim fileName As Variant
fileName = Dir(root_file_location_func & "\") 'The slash at the ends makes the directory all the files in the folder instead of just that folder



'Loop through all files in a folder
While fileName <> ""

If fileName = rh_part_file_name & ".CATPart" Or fileName = rh_part_file_name Then
    'MsgBox fileName & "!!!"
    rh_folder_lookup = True
    Exit Function
End If

fileName = Dir  'Set the fileName to the next file

Wend 'Wend means end when the condition is true



End Function
```